# How do I print from a jagged array?

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays, console.writeline

I just got onto the topic of Jagged Arrays, and im testing out one that im curious aboout.
it is: int[,][] jaggedArr = new int[1, 2][];

I was wondering what I have done wrong about the piece of code that I have come up with.
IT DOESNT WORK, AND I AM NOT FAMILIAR WITH THE FIX.

As you can see, I am trying to print the number "11".

```
class JaggedArrays
{            
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int[,][] jaggedArr = new int[1, 2][];

        jaggedArr[0, 0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        jaggedArr[0, 1] = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        jaggedArr[0, 2] = new int[] { 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

        jaggedArr[1, 0] = new int[] { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
        jaggedArr[1, 1] = new int[] { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 };
        jaggedArr[1, 2] = new int[] { 25, 26, 27 };

        Console.WriteLine(jaggedArr[0, 2][2]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work? What is the output you actually get? Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You messed up your array dimensions that is why.
You specify the outer array as int[1,2] (meaning the max index you can use is jaggedArr[0,1].

You are using jaggedArr[1,2] so your array needs to be at least int[2,3].
Clear?

Comment: it doesn't work cause 2 is outside of the boundaries. indexes are 0 valued. if you want to access 2. element you need to use 1 as index

Comment: @OliverBernhardt yes! I cant believe i got so many responses, I was about to post an answer that I did edit it to [2,3]! But it doesnt make sense to why it doesnt count in elements anymore.